# Passing Additional Parameters in Windsor castle

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle

Is it possible to pass additional parameters for resolving a type using Windsor IoC?  I know that there is a way to use anonymous args, but is it possible to pass this in addition to other constructor parameters which get resolved by the conatiner?

For example, my class is below:

```
interface IService
{
    void methodA();
}

public class MyService (Iproductrespository a, ITenderRepository  b, object context) : IService
{    
    public void methodA()
    {
    }
    ....
}
```

Now I want to resolve it using `Container.Resolve<IService>(new { id = 1 })`.  All my interfaces are registerd with the container.

Comment: The constructor of `MyService` (assuming that is the constructor) doesn't even have an `id` argument.  Why does that `Resolve` statement not satisfy your needs?  Are you looking for something cleaner that doesn't use the container directly?

Comment: My question is can I mix the constructor arguments ie two of them are (here the repositories) not passed during the call to Resolve and the third one is being passed during the Resolve call , I need to pass an object as the third argument which I know only during runtime.

Comment: Sure you can do that, and writing a small app to test that is easy.  If you want to avoid using the container, look at creating a [typed factory](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility.md) for your service.

Comment: @Patrick , I got It working now , You are right the issue was with the name of the third argument